# Hibernate - Audit table edit

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, liquibase, hibernate-envers, liquibase-hibernate

i would like to better understand the behavior of Hibernate Envers..
Here's the problem :
(PostgreSQL) I have this:

```
Person  (
          id bigint not null, 
          job character varying(10)
)
```

plus its  "_aud" table Person_AUD

Now, i have to do this change:

```
ALTER TABLE Person
ADD COLUMN group varchar (10);
```

And, after that, something like this :

```
UPDATE TABLE Person
SET group='unemployed'
WHERE job=null;
```

My questions are: what does Hibernate do to my _aud table when i run the "alter table?
And, what does Hibernate do to my_aud table when i run the "update"?

I ask this because i can't try it(i have to do this "manually" using Liquibase so I am asking it to you :) )

Answer (score 0):

Working off the assumption that column `group` is to be audited, you'll need to alter `Person_AUD` as well just like you did with the `Person` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Person_AUD 
ADD COLUMN group varchar(10)
```

Since the field is `NULL`-able, it is entirely up to you whether its necessary to also execute a similar update statement on the `Person_AUD` table.  If you want, it would be:

```
UPDATE Person_AUD 
   SET group = 'unemployed' 
 WHERE job is NULL
```

It's important to note that the number of rows updated in the `Person_AUD` table will not necessarily be the same number of updated rows from your `Person` table, as the audit table may contain multiple rows with differing revisions for the same primary key from `Person`.

Comment: yes, really thanks for your reply..but i think you missed my real question :
"what does Hibernate do to my_aud table when i run the "update"?"

For example:
I have Person table :

ID     JOB
0       null


After the "alter" and "update" it will be like this :

Person :

ID     JOB        GROUP
0       null         unemployed


How does the Person_AUD table will be?
Does it will create a new row including a new REV and adding the REVEND?

Comment: Are you using the hbm2ddl configuration setting with `update` ?